# Grouping on conditional column

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to generate a specific type of result set. I want to create a new column to mark a number so I can group accordingly.

As per below image TRXCODE 8202 is a GST code which contains 10% value in TRAMT coulmn of any other row.  in this case row# 10 contains 15 in TRAMT column which is 10% of rows # 5 (150).

Row# 4 & 9 (should be in one group)- TRAMT on row# 4 is the 10% of row# 9 TRAMT
Row# 6 & 8 (should be in one group)- TRAMT on row# 6 is the 10% of row# 8 TRAMT
Row# 12 & 15 (should be in one group)   same as above as per row reference
Row# 14 & 17 (should be in one group)

Numbers in GroupCol I just entered as example can by any figures.

[image]

This is the result set

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResult 
(TID INT, CUSTOMER INT, TRBATCH INT, TRDATE DATETIME,  TRREF INT
 ,  TRXCODE VARCHAR(10),  TRAMT DECIMAL(19,2),  TRTYPE VARCHAR(20))
 GO
 INSERT INTO #TempResult
 VALUES (113, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '1251', 6875.00,  'Receipt'),
        (114, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '1707', 150.00,   'Receipt'),
        (115, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '1723', 150.00,   'Receipt'),
        (116, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '1730', 150.00,   'Receipt'),
        (117, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '1777', 150.00,   'Receipt'),
        (119, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '8104', 299.00,   'Receipt'),
        (120, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '8202', 15.00,    'Receipt'),
        (121, 13294, 7246, '2005-05-03', 13827, '8202', 15.00,    'Receipt'),
        (122, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '1061', -5450.00, 'Refund'),
        (124, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '1703', 200.00,   'Refund'),
        (125, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '1723', -150.00,  'Refund'),
        (126, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '1730', -150.00,  'Refund'),
        (127, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '1777', -150.00,  'Refund'),
        (128, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '8104', -299.00,  'Refund'),
        (129, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '8202', -15.00,   'Refund'),
        (130, 13294, 7647, '2005-06-28', 13087, '8202', -15.00,   'Refund')
```

Comment: Why isn't `TID=115` and `TID=120` grouped together?

Comment: Hi Ajay Gupta, Thanks for reaching for help - Yes it can be I just mark those color as example TID115 and 120 can be in group